# Shutdown Flask server from scheduled job

Tags: python, linux, flask, python-multithreading, apscheduler

I'm running a flask server and an apscheduler background scheduler. I want the program to periodically restart itself.

I restart the application using the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
kill $(ps aux | grep 'python' | awk '{print $2}')
sleep 5
cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )"
python server.py
```

When I start the server without this script, then execute this script from another terminal it successfully kills the other process and starts the server.

But when the scheduler calls this script, flask gives me an 'error, socket in use'. Why does executing this from another terminal shutdown the server and free the socket, but executing it from inside the scheduler leave the socket in use?

How can I make the script my scheduler runs totally shutdown my server?

1 month later and I still haven't gotten an answer to this question :(

To clarify, I do not want a workaround that makes it so I don't need to restart the server. I want the server to have the ability to restart itself.

For now I am going to use the workaround of setting the server to start on boot, and then restarting the entire computer.

Comment: To have a proper production ready setup deploy Flask with WSGI. This should eliminate the need for restarts. The server built into Flask is for developent not for production.

Comment: @KlausD. Restarting the server is the end goal here, not a means to an end.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to restart the server periodically?

Comment: @stamaimer I want the server to update itself from a git repository. 
Every week: Shutdown, pull from repository, then start itself up.

It is a requirement that every piece of this process be changeable from the repository.

I KNOW this sounds like a horrible practice. Im aware that it sounds like something out of your nightmares. But it's what I want my server to do.

Let me know if you need any specific details

Comment: I think it's a good idea to use the webhook of GitHub.

Comment: @stamaimer I will be doing that! But the problem I have isnt doing the git pull. My problem is making the server restart itself.